# Unable to diagnose the problem with MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have defined the following stored procedure to add/update a table called `ImportedProduct`.

If the primary key, `ImportedProductId` is provided and is greater than zero, then update the exiting record otherwise insert a new one:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrUpdateImportedProduct (
    IN ImportedProductId BIGINT,
    IN UniqueThirdPartyCode VARCHAR(64),
    IN BranchId BIGINT
) 
BEGIN
    IF ImportedProductId <= 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO ImportedProduct(UniqueThirdPartyCode, BranchId)
        VALUES(UniqueThirdPartyCode, BranchId);
    ELSE
        UPDATE 
            ImportedProduct
        SET
            UniqueThirdPartyCode = UniqueThirdPartyCode, 
            BranchId = BranchId
        WHERE  
            ImportedProductId = ImportedProductId;
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Now I run the following code to update an existing row:

```
CALL AddOrUpdateImportedProduct (1, 'y-105', 24);
```

I can see that the record with with `ImportedProductId = 1` exists in the table, but I am getting the following error:

> You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without
>   a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure `ImportedProductId = ImportedProductId` holds always.. Perhaps rename your variable or add an alias to the updated table.

Comment: Well, ofcourse it does not hold if they are ```NULL``` or ```NaN```.. But that's not the point here